# Most efficient way to combine and separate numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I need to combine 2 numpy arrays (same lenght) into a large array and then decouple the array back to original. I know how to combine the array but not sure how to decouple it.

So, combining array

```
x=np.random.randint(5, size=(100000, 3))
y=np.random.randint(5, size=(100000, 1))
a=np.hstack((x,y))
```

now, I am not sure how to get x and y back again. I have tried

```
(_x,_y)=a.shape
_x=-_x
nx=a[:,0]
ny=a[:,_x:,]
```

And forwhatever reason, I am not getting my correct, x and y.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It looks like [`numpy.hsplit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html#numpy.hsplit) is the reverse of `numpy.hstack`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x.shape` is `(100000, 3)` and `y.shape` is `(100000, 1)`. [`np.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) concatenates arrays along the second (column) dimension, so `a.shape == (100000, 4)`. That means that `x` corresponds to the first 3 columns of `a`, and `y` corresponds to the last column.

You could separate them using [slice indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing), like this:

```
x1 = a[:, :3]   # the first 3 columns of a
y1 = a[:, 3:]   # the remaining column of a
```

What might have confused you is that when you index with an integer you reduce the dimensionality of the returned array by 1. For example, you might have expected `a[:, 3]` (the fourth column of `a`, since Python indexing starts at 0) to be the same as `y`, but instead it is a `(100000,)` 1D array rather than a `(100000, 1)` 2D array like `y`.

To avoid this you can either use slice indexing like in my example above, or you can insert a new dimension of size 1 using `np.newaxis`:

```
y2 = a[:, 3, np.newaxis]
```

or by calling [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) on the output:

```
y2 = a[:, 3].reshape(-1, 1)
```

The -1 expands this dimension automatically to match the size of `a`.